Sequential bot messages in Gradio ChatInterface
Starting with very basic example :
import random
import gradio as gr

def random_response(message, history):
    return random.choice(["Yes", "No"])

demo = gr.ChatInterface(random_response)

demo.launch()

I'd like to return from random_response 2 answers that would appear in Chatbot as 2 bot answers one after another.
[EDIT}
Example :
User : Hello!!!
Bot : Hello!!!
Bot : How are you ?

Second message from bot is out without some response from user.
Actually I see now that I can't print history inside the random_response function . The variable is here , but print(history) in Colab doesn't work
Any clue how to do it ?

Type anything in the chat and the bot will return "yes" or "no"

can you explain more? like what is the expected input and output.

I would propose to go with custom chat interface. I don't think that current version of prebuild ChatInterface can do the work that you want it to do.
import gradio as gr
import random
import time

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    chatbot = gr.Chatbot()
    msg = gr.Textbox()
    clear = gr.Button("Clear")

    def user(user_message, history):
        return "", history + [[user_message, None]]

    def bot_message(history):
        bot_message = random.choice(["How are you?", "I love you", "I'm very hungry"])
        history.append((None, bot_message))
        return history        

    def bot2_message(history):
        bot_message = random.choice(["Hello2"])
        history.append((None, bot_message))
        return history


    msg.submit(user, [msg, chatbot], [msg, chatbot], queue=False).then(
        bot_message, chatbot, chatbot
    ).then(
        bot2_message, chatbot, chatbot
    )
    clear.click(lambda: None, None, chatbot, queue=False)

demo.launch()


